# Im getting 401 when i try to validate token, after a successfully login,

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm working on a small project using **VueJS** and **Vue Router** and **Laravel** in the backend.

I tried too many times to use navigation guard but didn't succeed,

I have a login component works really fine, this is my login method : (as you can see I'm using **localStorage** for my token and some other data)

**Login.vue**

```
login() {

      axios.post('http://proudata.test/api/login', this.user).then(response => {

        if (response.data.data.isLogged == true) {
          
          localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.data));

          router.push({ name: 'dashboard' });

        }

      }).catch(error => {
        this.error = true;
        this.message = error.response.data.message
      });

    }
```

my issue is with the navigation guard and exactly in **beforeEach**, I try to validate the token each time the user click on another page to check if the token is still alive or expired :

this is my **routes.js** file :

```
router.beforeEach(async (routeTo, routeFrom, next) => {
 
  const authRequired = routeTo.matched.some((route) => route.meta.authRequired)
  
  if (!authRequired) return next()

    // **THE PROBLEM IS HERE IM GETTING 401 JUST AFTER LOGIN**
    await client.get('validate-token').then(() => {
      next();
    }).catch(() => {
      next({ name: 'login' })
    });
 
});
```

and I have an axios client file that I use to send the header each time as you can see :

**Client.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

let userData = localStorage.getItem('token');

let authenticated = {data:{}};

if(userData !== null){
    authenticated = JSON.parse(userData);
}

const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: ((authenticated.data.domain !== null) ? authenticated.data.domain : 'http://domain.test/api')
});

client.interceptors.request.use(config => {

    if(userData !== null){

        config.headers.Authorization = authenticated.data.token ? `Bearer ${authenticated.data.token}` : null; 
    }

    return config;

});

export default client;
```

the problem is : once I click on login I get my response like that : (which is correct, logged successfully )

Server Response (201), logged successfully

```
{
   data:{
     isLogged:true,
     token: gkljdfslkgjdfklgjfdlkgj,
     domain: http://user.multitenancy.test
   }
}
```

then I get an error in validate-token I get 401, is like I'm not sending the token that I have saved in the localStorage as Bearer Authorization (check the interceptor please)

As you can see in my login method, token is saved in the localStorage, but im sending null in the Bearer Authorization,  ( the problem only when I push login button to login ) and I see my localStorage data in the Devtools fine.

probably I should not verify the token in beforeEach ? What do you think the issue ?

Comment: The token validation endpoint seems redundant. All of your endpoints need to validate the token anyway and you can return 401 from them all the same. What purpose does this endpoint serve?

Comment: @Etheryte
the endpoint is because Im using a multi tenancy,  each subdomain = a database

Comment: This error occurs because laravel has a built-in CSRF protection and it expects a CSRF token in the request. Read documentation for more info. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf Also this following post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41867849/4982097

Comment: @Engin I don't think that is the problem, because the problem is in my beforeEach, 
im not sending the bearer token, since i just click on login and the token just savec in the localstorage

Comment: what the `validation-token` end point does?

Comment: @GiacomoM   http://user.multitenancy.test/api/validate-token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get token from localStorage every time to get fresh data.

config.baseURL also need to set every time in your interceptor.

```
import axios from 'axios';

let userData = localStorage.getItem('token');

let authenticated = {data:{}};

if(userData !== null){
    authenticated = JSON.parse(userData);
}

const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: ((authenticated.data.domain !== null) ? authenticated.data.domain : 'http://domain.test/api')
});

client.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    // get token from localStorage every time to get fresh data
    let userData = localStorage.getItem('token');

    let authenticated = {data:{}};
    
    if(userData !== null){
        authenticated = JSON.parse(userData);
        config.headers.Authorization = authenticated.data.token ? `Bearer ${authenticated.data.token}` : null;
        config.baseURL = ((authenticated.data.domain !== null) ? authenticated.data.domain : 'http://domain.test/api')
    }

    return config;

});

export default client;
```

Comment: I'm getting Cors issue now

Comment: so I think you solved this problem. Check CORS problem here https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: I did install fruitcake, but still have the same issue